# Completely Removing dataframe rows in R. Stop table() returning 0 for removed data

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, pie-chart

I want to create a piechart out of the number of occurrences in a dataframe column. However there are 5 words I want to remove before I make the piechart. I have a dataframe and I can remove these rows using something like:

```
subset(df, tag != "rubbish")
```

However if I then plot using

```
pie(table(df$tag)
```

Rubbish still appears in the piechart, but with Zero instances.

`table(df$tag)` before subset gives me something like:

```
tag1  3
tag2  7
rubbish 9
```

and after:

```
tag1  3
tag2  7
rubbish 0
```

Is there anyway to remove rubbish completely without table() returning zero? I have tried `table(df$tag, exclude="rubbish")` but there is more than 1 tag I want to remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that `df$tag` is a factor, or categorical variable. Deleting a certain category from the factor does not change the levels that are associated with the factor. `table` iterates over the levels associated with the factor. Even if the level is empty `table`does this, hence `rubbish 0`. The solution is to recreate the factor after you deleted the tag:

```
subset(df, tag != "rubbish")
levels(df$tag)
df$tag = factor(df$tag)
levels(df$tag)
table(df$tag)
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: perfect! The solution is great but extra thanks for explaining the problem.

Comment: Thanks also for that Ben. It is worth me knowing both versions as doing things the long way round often helps me understand whats happening. Slow in learning R.. but I'm getting there :)